# Proving differentiability in a point

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f : I = (a, b) \to \Bbb R$ and $a < c < b$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $I \setminus \{c\}$ and $\lim \limits _{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$. If $\lim \limits _{x \to c} f′ (x) = L$, show that $f$ is differentiable at $x = c$ and $f′ (c) = L$.

I know how to find $f'(c) = L$ but how to prove $f$ is differentiable at $x=c$?

Comment: Please edit your post, use LaTeX notaton for formulas.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that $$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=L.$$

Notice that as $\lim\limits_{h\to0}f(c+h)=f(c)$ the numerator converges to $0$. Since the numerator and denominator are differentiable functions on $I$ except at $c$, we can apply L'Hoptials rule. Therefore
$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f^\prime(c+h)}{1}=L .$$

L'Hopitals in particular implies the existence of the limit and so $f$ is differentiable at $c$.